# how to accessing data in a php object

Tags: php

I am trying to the balance in a PHP object, I tried everything but am getting array to string conversion error, here is the string

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Balances retrieved",
    "data": [
        {
        "currency": "NGN",
        "balance": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

its a response from a remote server, i am trying to get the balance, i tried

```
$response->data->balance

json_decode($response)->data->balance

json_decode($response[0])->data->balance
```

but none of them worked, the response from the remote server is stored in a variable called `$response`
How can i get the balance from the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is an array

```
json_decode($response)->data[0]->balance
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example, that I created: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/414f23b1a09221ed5bd7f299f5eb73a2f9f932b1

First you decode the JSON string
Then access **data** array at the index 0, so data[0]
And then data[0]->balance, access object property '**balance**'

Answer (score 0):

Gerard's answer is right.

Also you can naviguate the result of a json_decode function in array mode.

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Balances retrieved",
    "data": [
        {
        "currency": "NGN",
        "balance": 0
        }
    ]
}';
$response = json_decode($json);
echo $response["data"][0]["balance"];
echo $response->data[0]->balance;
```

Using a variable to register the decode answer will save you time.